# Handling LocalSessionFactoryBean exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datasource, sessionfactory

This is the first time, when I use LocalSessionFactoryBean instead SessionFactory and I have a problem: if my server can't connect to database, @Bean method throws an exception and whole app closes. But here is a strange thing: exception is throwing AFTER bean method return object.

```
@Bean
LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(Properties.hibernate.packages);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(databaseSettings.getHibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```

so try-catch doesn't work here. When Spring initialize beans it runs sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet() method by itself. So in that time exception is throwing. After all I have next log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
     Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [app/db/Hibernate.class]: 
     Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
     org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
```

What is the best way to handle db connection error in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observed behaviour is totally logic to me. The code presented in your question merely configures the `SessionFactory` internally. Once the resulting `LocalSessionFactoryBean` is returned (and used by other code fragments), an attempt is made to *actually* connect with the database you have configured this way.

In case the configured `DataSource` - obtained via `getDataSource()` - encounters an error while establishing a (first) connection you will hit a `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException` as described.

*Note: For details, you'd have to provide more pieces of the stack trace.*

As a counter measure, you could add the following "connection check" to the above code fragment before returning:

```
@Bean
LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    DataSource ds = getDataSource();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(ds);
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(Properties.hibernate.packages);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(databaseSettings.getHibernateProperties());

    // conduct an early connection attempt which auto-closes the opened connection 
    try (Connection con = ds.getConnection(username, password)) {  
        // if you reach this line, connections to the DB can be established.
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    } catch (Exception ex {
        // handle exceptions with one or more of these steps
        // 1. log the problem to somewhere, console...
        // 2. re-try connection attempt?
        // 3. escalate by throwing a self-defined RuntimeException 
        // .. and shutdown the application in controlled manner? 
    }
}
```

For reference see also Oracle's guide to [Connecting with DataSource Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html).

*Hint*: You could also consider to use a "PooledDataSource" for many reasons (see details in the aforementioned DataSource guide).

Hope it helps.